# Could there be a city in a bottle in a city in a bottle?

Tags: dc, superman

I have not found any canonical references that detail Brainiac's city-shrinking technology, but I suspect it functions similarly to other shrinking technology detailed in the DC universe.

If Brainiac managed to shrink the Fortress of Solitude while the City of Kandor was bottled within, would the City of Kandor shrink any further? Or, is it assumed to be already compressed to its minimum size?

In the latter case, what would happen if Brainiac attempted to shrink the Fortress? Are there any canonical or speculative analyses of this paradox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to give answers like this, but the only answer that can be given (until it happens 'on-screen' or is explicitly answered in the books) is that what will happen depends on what needs to happen for the purposes of the story.

I would *expect* that everything would shrink the same, so the city in a bottle would then have a city in a bottle in it.

If needed, though, it could do anything from make the city disappear, invert the two (so that the Fortress would be replaced by Kandor, which would then have the Fortress in a bottle), shrink the city of Kandor until it was so small it vanished (possibly into time and space, to reappear later), or whatever else was required for plot.